# A way to perform lossless JPG edits in Adobe Photoshop CS6?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, jpeg, image-editing

I perform lots of small edits of JPGs daily on my computer, and was wondering whether there was a way to perform cropping and rotation without the loss of quality during recompression. I know there are programs out there like BetterJPG which do this, but shouldn't this function already exist in Photoshop?

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Not what you asked, but IrfanView also does this

Comment: I have an earlier version of PS, but believe it does these operations losslessly, at least for 90° rotations and rectangular crops.

Comment: Can you losslessly edit a .JPG? Any changes to the image must be made while it is decompressed... and the only way to get a modified, decompressed image back into a .JPG is to recompress it... Cropping isn't just a "Oh, let's cut out this data here" once you start to involve compression.